# What is a "Systemd login session"?

Tags: systemd, logind

I read https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=825394#221, but I wonder what  a "systemd login session" is? Is it  called more frequently as a "systemd logind session"?

Is it some process? (like a `lxsession` process?) What is its process name or command name?

Is it itself a process session or process group? Is it related to the process session lead by the`login`  process?

Thanks.

Comment: Cgroup. Again. You keep asking, just refuse every answer you get.

Comment: It's related to `login` because it is the program who do the authentication. Also you can see clearly `login` running inside the session when you login on the virtual console.

Comment: If I have logged into the virtual console for desktop environment, but have not logged into any text virtual console, there is no `login` process, but only `systemd-logind` process. Why is that?

Comment: Because when you login by Display Manager (or Login Manager, whatever name you like), `agetty` or any kind of `getty` doesn't run at all. The display manager do the authentication then talk to logind to create session.

Comment: What  played  the role of `systemd-login`,  when sysvinit was used?

Comment: ConsoleKit, I believe. Since it's an independent project from `sysvinit`, people might use other apps as session manager. But nowadays, systemd just force you to use its own components, or it will be kind of broken.